# Automated data copy in Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, automation, copy

My goal is to automate a weekly copy program. I'd like to copy a column of data from one worksheet to the next blank column of another worksheet within the same spreadsheet so I can see trends over time.

I've spent 12+ hours working on this and scrounging the web for code that might work and I'm still stuck. This is what I have so far but it keeps counting and filtering cells within a column instead of cells within a row.

```
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var origin_sheet = ss.getSheetByName('COPYFROM');
  var origin_value = origin_sheet.getRange(2, 6, origin_sheet.getMaxRows(), 1).getValues();

  var destination_sheet = ss.getSheetByName('COPYTO');
  var countCols = destination_sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, destination_sheet.getMaxColumns()).getValues();
  //FILTER WORKING: But it's filtering/counting cells in col A...
  var filt = countCols.filter((col) => col != '');
  
  var destination_range = destination_sheet.getRange(1, countCols+1, 500, 1);
  destination_range.setValue(origin_value);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function myfunk() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const ssh = ss.getSheetByName('COPYFROM');
  const svs = ssh.getRange(2, 6, ssh.getLastRow() - 1).getValues();
  const dsh = ss.getSheetByName('COPYTO');
  const dshsr = 2;//destination sheet data start row
  dsh.getRange(dshsr, dsh.getLastColumn() + 1, svs.length, svs[0].length).setValues(svs);
}
```